# Testing for object equality by comparing the toString() representations of objects

Tags: java

Following on from [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/149001/are-there-any-situtations-where-having-a-data-model-in-which-all-your-enititie) - how do you explain to someone that this is just crazy!:

```
boolean someMethod(Map<String, Object> context) {
    Object object = context.get("someProperty") 
    Object another = context.get("anotherProperty") 

    return object.toString().equals(another.toString());
}
```

Apparently the reason for why `Object.equals(...)` is not used is that "what's contained in the Map is not concretely known, but is definitely known to be one of the primitive wrappers i.e. `String`, `Double`, `Boolean`, etc... and that `Boolean.TRUE` is required to be `equal(...)` to the `String` "TRUE"".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's wrong because there is no contract (not even an informal expectation!) for `toString()` that guarantees that any subclass of `Object` will define it in a way compatible with an equivalence relationship (read the javadoc for `Object.equals()` to see what I mean).

It may work for a class where you know that `toString()` is compatible with `equals`, but this is not the case for the values in `Map<String, Object>`!

For an obvious example where almost certainly the method doesn't do what you would expect, imagine a subclass of `Object` that does not override `toString()`. In that case, the String representation of your instance is a function of the class name and the object's hashCode. Almost certainly *not* what you want to use to test for equality.

Comment: Any comments on this part of the question?
>> "what's contained in the Map is not concretely known, but is definitely known to be one of the intrinsic wrappers i.e. String, Double, Boolean, etc... and that Boolean.TRUE is required to be equal(...) to the String "TRUE""

Comment: When in Rome, do as the Romans do: Java is a strong, static-typed language. Boolean.TRUE may be equal (IDK) to String "TRUE", but this is duck typing at hand and considered bad practice in Java. Also, what's guaranteed is that what's contained in the map is `Object`. Assuming otherwise is a bad idea, again because of the Java paradigms. Reminds me of "You can write Fortran in any language".

Comment: @loudsight What do you mean, "intrinsic wrappers"? In any case, `String`, `Boolean` and `Double` all have well-defined `equal` methods, which you might as well use (though I'm not sure it's numerically safe to use `Double.equals()`, but that's another issue). In the general case, `toString()` is not meant for equality tests, so don't use it for that.

Comment: Actually, I meant to say primitive rather than instrinsic. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class

Comment: @loudsight Java primitive wrappers all have well-defined `equals` methods. You absolutely do NOT need to convert to String.

Comment: The fact that a method accepts an argument of type `Map<String, Object>` does not imply that it will behave usefully with all instances of that type.  If the contract *for `someMethod`* specifies that it is only required to behave usefully when the passed-in `Map` meets certain criteria, including the fact that it maps two particular strings to objects that override `toString()` in some particular fashion, the fact that `Object` imposes no particular meaning for `toString()` would be irrelevant.

Comment: @supercat That would be a poor use of Java's type system. In some cases its limitations make this unavoidable, but whenever possible use real types and avoid the "javadocs-as-types" as you suggest, which is a bad practice. If the method doesn't work correctly for all `Object`s, then for heaven's sake, don't pass it an `Object`. Anything else is not taking full advantage of the type system, which you must not do *unless you have a good reason*. I suppose you *could* program in Java as if it were Python, but what would be the point? :)

Comment: @supercat To put it another way, whenever it's possible to encode the property "the passed-in `Map` meets certain criteria" as a type in a statically typed language, please do so!

Comment: @AndresF.: Unfortunately, Java has no concept of a type which would be stored as a reference to a `Map` but be statically bound to different methods.  It is necessary instead to create an extra wrapper object and route all actions through it.  Doing that is generally semantically superior to requiring that pre-existing types be used in specific ways, but imposes some extra run-time overhead.  Often not important, but sometimes devastating.

Comment: @supercat I know; that's one of its limitations. As a general rule though, and unless you have very specific reasons not to, you should avoid passing `Object` to Java methods if they will only work with some subclasses (aka "avoid writing partial functions whenever possible"). Of course, lots of existing Java libraries work that way; let us learn from their horrible mistakes :)

Comment: @AndresF.: Java's type system has some pretty severe limitations; sometimes it's worth trying to encode the semantics of one's types within it and sometimes it isn't. As a simple example, suppose one has a map which where 99.9% of entries will map to a `String`, but some may map to more than one, and performance is somewhat important. If consumers will likely want to handle the single-item case differently from the multi-item case, is it better to use a `Map<key,String[]>` and create a dedicated single-element array for each item, or a `Map<key,Object>` ...

Comment: ...and require that every item be either a `String` or a `String[]`?  Wrapping every string in an array would be possible, but it would have significant cost; if consumers are expected to handle the single- and multi-item cases separately, wrapping every string in a `String[1]` would add a lot of overhead but not save consumers any work.  Without seeing how code is used, it's hard to say if `Object` is appropriate or not.

Comment: @supercat I'm familiar with the limitations of Java's type system. Your example seems very contrived, and I doubt you'll gain much by using `Object` instead of a different, more useful type. What happens when I `put` a value in that map that isn't a `String` or a `String[]`? Ah, yes: I should have read the javadoc! If only there was a way to somehow tell the compiler that I cannot put an instance of `Integer` in the map! ... I hope you get my point :)

Comment: @AndresF.: If the `Map` isn't public, how are "you" going to do that?  The owner of of a mutable type is responsible for ensuring that its contents uphold any invariants the owner requires.  The fact that the owner never exposes the `Map` to anything that would add something improper to it will ensure that it never has anything improper added.

Comment: @supercat I'm sorry, I don't even understand your example anymore, or how it relates to the original question. This would probably something for us to discuss in another place.  Feel free to write your own answer if you disagree with my advise that no, in general you shouldn't rely on `toString` to compare `Object`s!

Comment: @AndresF.: In simple terms: if the above were part of a public API, I would deem it bizarre at best.  If it's part of a private API, however, the appropriateness of the method would depend upon how it was being used.  As an alternate--perhaps more realistic example--suppose that a class needed to work with HTML strings, and needed methods to import and export in both escaped and unescaped formats.  If most strings will be identical in both formats, it might be helpful to have a class which holds escaped and unescaped formats, and have `ToString` report the unescaped format.  For efficiency...

Comment: ...however, one might want to store things as `String` if both escaped and unescaped formats were equivalent, and as `EscapableString` when they differ.  If the method never stored anything in the `Map` other than instances of `String` or `EscapableString`, then regarding things as equal when the `ToString()` matches might be perfectly reasonable.  I don't particularly expect the above code is being used for such purpose, but if so would not consider such a design unreasonable.

Comment: @supercat It sounds as if you *really* want to write an answer instead of commenting in mine :)

Comment: @AndresF.: What do you think of my answer?

Answer (score 7):

It's just crazy, because it can go wrong, because string representations are not [canonical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form):

```
Double zeroDouble = new Double(0);
Integer zeroInteger = new Integer(0);
zeroDouble.doubleValue() == zeroInteger.doubleValue(); // true
zeroDouble.toString().equals(zeroInteger.toString());  // false ("0.0" vs "0")

File file1 = new File("file.txt");
File file2 = new File("FILE.TXT");
file1.equals(file2);            // true in windows, false in unix
file1.toString().equals(file2); // false ("file.txt" vs. "FILE.TXT")
```

Comment: Actually, `zeroDouble.equals(zeroInteger)` is false.

Comment: Oops, I stand corrected. Numerical comparisons are almost never trivial :)

Answer (score 0):

The indicated method would be very odd as part of a public API.  Whether or not it is crazy as a private or protected part of a class would depend upon how it was being used.  The method appears to encapsulate two different quirky aspects, either of which could plausibly be justifiable in some contexts but not others; while it would seem unlikely that both would be justifiable, there's no particular reason why they couldn't be.

The first quirky aspect is the fact that the method is searching for particular fixed strings within the maps.  Such behavior is generally ugly (and it would probably be better if the strings were defined as constants) but could be justifiable if:

1. The map is never exposed to code outside the package.
2. It is necessary to use some collection type to store aggregates, each of which consists of a mapping plus a few other bits of information).
3. The use of the encapsulated mapping is such that no key could possibly conflict with the strings that are used for the "few other bits of information".
4. The mapping is used so much more than the other bits of information stored within the advocate that using a class which contained a `Map` along with the other bits of information would be much more cumbersome than using a map which has a few bits of information associated with magic keys.

Some languages and frameworks would provide alternate means of attaching supplemental information to a type, but the approach indicated here is sometimes the most practical one given Java's type system.

The second ugly aspect is that the code is comparing two objects' `ToString` values as a means of comparing the objects.  In most cases, either the objects will be strings (in which case one could just compare them), or they would be some other type which has some attribute of type `String` such a name, in which case one should cast the objects to that other type, call `GetName` on both instances, and compare the resulting strings.  If, however, the majority of table entries would only need to store strings, but a few might need to have an entry which combines a string with a small amount of supplemental information, it may in some cases be easier to store things in the table as type `Object` with the expectation that every entry will either be a `String`, or be some known kind of object.  Since Java's type system has no concept of "thing which will either be type1 or type2", using `Object`, though ugly, may be the only practical alternative in cases where one of the types is something like `String` which would share no common ancestor--other than `Object`--with any user class.

Answer (score -6):

If you are keenly interested to know about Object Equality then use can use the method of 
class Object.

int hashCode() gives the integer value called  hashCode which pertain to an object.

```
definitely the hashcode differs object to object.
     it's a easiest way to identify object equality.
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that equal objects have the same hashcode, and similarly there is no guarantee that non-equal objects have differing hashcodes.

Comment: This is a serious misunderstanding of what `hashCode` does.